# Why do manufacturers label differently seemingly identical components?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, manufacturing, replacement

I am not sure if this is the relevant place to ask this (I think it is.)

I am still relatively new to the electronic design world, but I notice that a series of parts (example - Torex XCLxxx) can feature ICs whose specifications can be 90% identical.

This is understandable, but I recently had to replace an IC which was discontinued. Apparently, a year or so later, the same manufacturer (not sure if I'm allowed to mention specifics,) releases a 'new' component, which conveniently can be a pin-to-pin perfect replacement for the discontinued one. After looking into the datasheet of this 'new' component and meticulously comparing it with the other one, the only differences I can find are an 0.04 mm increase in height and a slight difference of some internal resistances.

Now it seems to me that it would be much easier to just redefine the old datasheet and continue selling the 'new' component under the old name without announcing its discontinuing (and save clients the hassle of searching for replacements.) Is this a common ocurrence? Does it have some sort of strategic benefit?

Comment: You're allowed to mention specifics--it might help get a more detailed and specific answer, if that's what you want.

Comment: ST Microelectronics does the opposite with STM32: the different chip revisions have same product code. Sometimes they have quite critical errata in the earlier revisions, and you have no way to know what revision you get when ordering parts.

Comment: I've seen Crucial (a quite reputable party, being Micron's direct-to-consumer arm after all) naff this up when they made a change to a DIMM design (from double-rank with a certain chip size to single rank with chips twice the size) that made new units incompatible with the motherboard I had at the time (thankfully, they continued making the old stuff under a slightly different P/N, which meant that it was merely a mildly embarrassing RMA, not a complete fail)

Comment: If they change the manufacturing process, they may change the part number so customers can tell between the old and the new part as there may be unknown small differences.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So there's differences. Thankfully, they decided not to use the same name for different things, that would be much more confusing than using different names for similar things.

Strategic benefit is not annoying customers by shipping slightly different products under the same label, which they then can't tell apart. If you needed the part with the new resistances, would you want to buy the old part? If not, what would you do if you saw 100000 pieces of the right part number in stock somewhere? Assume it's newly stock? Old stock?

Comment: It makes sense to define differences so customers can differentiate between them. However, these ones specifically do not seem significant enough to call for a whole new component creation. Also, wouldn't announcing the discontinuing of a component already annoy or disrupt much more? I get your point completely, any difference is significant in some designs. But also, I have had instances, where manufacturers would send a different batch (different characteristics) of the same component without announcing anything at all.

Comment: "these ones specifically do not seem significant enough to call for a whole new component creation" Says you. Maybe that's true for 90% of the chip vendor's customers. But what about the remaining 10%? For the 90% it's merely an inconvenience, and for the 10%, it means they can't even buy the chips anymore, because they don't know what they're getting. However, what you describe in your question does sound like a major change,as it indicates something changed about chip packaging. Going for a clearly distinguishable naming was the right thing to do.

Comment: Seems to me that this would be a good case to release it as a revision. e.g. if the old chip was part number 123, then this new one can be 123revB, 123.1, etc. The specific differences should be published and highlighted. This would make it findable by people looking for the old one without creating any confusion.

Answer (score 24):

The way the electronics industry is supposed to work (but rarely does):

- When you buy a component from a supposedly reputable component vendor like Arrow, Avnet etc, they are supposed to keep tabs on this component for you.
- When there are product changes and the vendor gets informed by this from the silicon manufacturer, they are supposed to send you a "*Product Change Notification*" (PCN), since they know you've bought the part in the past and is therefore likely interested in knowing about any changes.

  Most often this is stuff you don't really care about, like changed manufacturing site or bonding wire material used etc. Other stuff like the mentioned 0.04mm change or something like part label changes might not be of interest to you, but could be important to other customers.
- Similarly, when a part is discontinued, you are supposed to get an "*End of Life Notification*" (EOL), which should contain recommended replacement parts, if any, as well as a "*Last Time Buy*" (LTB) date.

This works worse now than ever, for historical reasons. Back in the days there were two different kind of component vendors:

- The reputed ones who had technical support, as well as good sales support, who was keeping an ear to the ground, keeping track of what was new and dodging any fluctuations in part availability by keeping parts in stock. And also keeping track of PCN, not recommended for new design, EOL part status etc.
- The "catalogue vendors" (Digikey, Mouser, RS, Farnell etc), who did business by sending out hard copy catalogues of everything they had in stock. You could only buy the parts they marketed and had in stock, with fast deliveries and usually higher prices. No support what-so-ever.

In the last decade or so, the line between these have blurred. The previously reputed vendors for some reason decided that they needn't be reputable no longer, so they cut down all sales support, fired their "FAE" (field application engineers) and stopped keeping parts in stock. Basically cancelling all reasons why you would want to do business with them. Also, plenty of silicon manufacturers nowadays allow you to buy the parts directly from them with no middle man, so why not do that.

At the same time, the "catalogue vendors" stopped sending out catalogues (there's the Internet) but also started aiming towards keeping more parts in stock and not having quite as outrageous pricing as before. Essentially taking over most of the business that the classic vendors decided that they didn't want any longer.

Collateral damage from this change of affairs with "catalogue vendors" taking over the market, is that nobody is keeping track of PCN or EOL notifications any longer. All vendors will surely claim that they do if you ask them, but they don't. At best, they'll tell you at the point you try to buy something: "Hey, this part went EOL 2 years ago. You can't buy it, bye bye."

In the best of worlds you'd get PCN/EOL directly from the silicon manufacturer, but they are too high and mighty to deal with annoyances like "customers" - we should just consider ourselves lucky that they allow us to buy their products. Thanks to all the company mergers between previous competitors (with the blessing of clueless governments around the world), most silicon manufacturers now have either monopoly or oligopoly on a certain kind of part. So they can behave as they please and if some annoying person contacts them and wants to buy their products, they could just tell them to get lost and come back in 52 weeks.

Answer (score 8):

I can only speak on behalf of one company I had the time to join over the summer. Manufacturers (of the chips) do not know  how specific your requirements are. What if your IC was to have a heat sink on it? A difference in height may affect performance.

Even minute changes in manufacturing could give uncertainty in the extremes of thermal capabilities.

Often it can be things such as a change in where the chip is manufactured, adding a letter at the end, usually in the notice documents they state the different production locations.

Comment: In many fields, designs may require many thousands of dollars worth of qualification testing prior to approval, and changing *anything* will require that the testing be redone.  Even if there's no reason to expect that changing some aspect of a product would affect its performance in an application, a non-trivial number of disasters have been caused by product changes that had unexpected consequences.  While the disasters may represent what would ordinarily be a trivial number of failures, the severity of the consequences makes the tolerable level of risk far below what it would otherwise be.

Comment: Agreed, but its is not always the case the entire retesting has to be redone for slight changed, vastly depends on the situation. Again i was only a summer placment so i dont know fully, but they delt with a lot of legacy products too and was a common issue with them when components would become "obselete"

Comment: My point was that some applications are far more tolerant regarding product variations than others.  In one scenario I know of, a supplier sold parts in different tolerance grades, and a vendor's manufacturing processes improved to that point that all manufactured products would pass what would have been the middle grade.  The manufacturer specified that it would could custom-produce batches of parts marked with the inferior grade (with a minimum order size) for customers who required that all assemblies be visually inspected to ensure that parts precisely match the required pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Offhand, two reasons spring to mind.

Firstly, you certify that your circuit works with specific components. If components are EoL'd and replacements are developed, then you need to re-test and re-recertify.
The IC company faking the names to pretend to be the same when they are not, would cause a serious problem, because you would not know if the ICs you were using were the ones you had tested and certified against, or merely some "pin-for-pin replacement".

Secondly, fake ICs are a major problem nowadays.

A fake IC is often a pin-for-pin replacement, but manufactured with far poorer tolerances, and far more cheaply, to pretend to be the original. If there are two lines which make equivalent chips, and you went with the pricier one, odds are good you had a reason. You wouldn't want to be sold one of the cheaper line, with the badge of the pricier one.

So you want to be able to identify these potential failures before you have to put out a massive recall of all your devices.

Back around 20 years ago, I worked for the company which still (so far as I know) makes the leading counterfeit IC detector, which works by taking the V/I curves between each of the pins, and saving this as a pin signature.

The idea is that even some untrained grunt in your goods inwards dept can slap the chip on the tester, get a green or a red, and pass or fail it.

So if your grunt slaps the IC in, selects "TI 123456-A" in the IC dropdown, but what he's been given is actually a "pin-to-pin perfect replacement" by some other company, branded as the "TI 123456-A", then the detector will show up red. It's not the same chip. It has the same specs, but it's made on a different die, and it's got a different pin signature. It *might* perform the same, but it's a fake.

Another thing that can happen is that what you ordered was a TI 123456-A, and what you got was a TI 123456-C. Then if both signatures exist in its DB, the detector can pop up saying that's what you got with a high certainty, and you can decide to keep and use the part, or you can send it back to your supplier and say "we invested a lot of money testing and certifying this equipment with the -A, we ordered the -A, so don't screw us around and give us the -C."

You wouldn't have that ability if they were both called "TI 123456-A".